# blender 2.79b graph editor not showing graphs

Tags: graph-editor

I opened it up like the tut vid said and I see no graphs for anything, I've clicked all of the button, and such and still nothing, what am i doing wrong, or is it blender?

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I downloaded the .blend and saw that just select the frames to appear in the rendering. Hold 'shift' and go by clicking on them.
[image]

Then just render.
[image]

Comment: @ElektroJavrski I'm trying to edit the graphs around  frame 629 to adjust the partial system on the cone for fireworks, not rendering all layers. Layer 3 is where the cone is at. the camera view is for my working area.

Comment: See this short video, it will solve your problem. I tested it on your project and it worked. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=df9LGwBg91A

Comment: : back: nope that is nothing like what I am doing, other than the explosion, what you gave me is called a work around, not a fix. I still have no graph editor for that or anything else that I'd need it for.  @ElektroJavrski

Comment: I'm starting a different file, and putting everything together in post.

Comment: I get a -1 points for telling a truth, someone gave me a work around, not a proper answer, then deciding the best thing to do is start over, and someone shmuck gives me a -1 point. Where mom and Dads fail they thrive.